# Titanic Dataset. Logistic Regression Model. Confusion Matrix gives 0 as output

Tags: logistic-regression, confusion-matrix, model-validation

I am running the logistic regression model on the Titanic Dataset with the below code:

```
#Modeling

#Split into train and test and fit the logistic regression model


titanic_train <- titanic_complete[1:891,]
titanic_test <- titanic_complete[892:1309,]

##############Logistic Regression ###############################

glm_model = glm(Survived~.,data= titanic_train, family = 'binomial')
summary(glm_model)


## Using anova() to analyze the table of devaiance
anova(glm_model, test="Chisq")


final_model = glm(Survived~Sex + Pclass + Age + SibSp + Cabin_f, data = titanic_train, family = 'binomial')
summary(final_model)

varImp(glm_model)

glm.pred <-predict(final_model, titanic_test, type = 'response')
glm.pred <- ifelse(glm.pred > 0.5, "yes", "no")

glm.pred

confusionMatrix(glm.pred, titanic_test$Survived)
```

As a result I've got this error message:

```
> confusionMatrix(glm.pred, titanic_test$Survived)
[1] no  yes
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
In Ops.factor(predictedScores, threshold) :
  ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
```

Cannot understand this error message and what is wrong. The model is working fine on the train data. 
I assume it is related to the threshold i apply to the Survived variable (which is a factor variable - 1,0).